# Finding the mean given the probability

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expectation, markov-chains, means

I'm doing some work on branching processes and would like to know where the process becomes extinct. If $X$ is the number of offspring of an individual, then the process goes extinct when $\mathbb{E}[X] \leq 1$.

I know that the probability that each cell in the first generation splits into $k$ individuals is $qp^k$, where $k \geq 0, p + q = 1$.

> For which values of the parameters $p,q$ does the process become extinct?

The answer says that the process becomes extinct if the mean number of offsprings is $\leq 1$. It then shows that $q \displaystyle\sum^\infty_{k=0}kp^k = \frac{p}{q}$.

Why do we start with $q \displaystyle\sum^\infty_{k=0}kp^k$? What does this have to do with the mean or the expected value?

Comment: It seems like $p$ and $q$ have been mixed up somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the spot, edited!

Comment: In that case, $q\sum_{k=0}^\infty kp^k$ is indeed the expected value of the offspring distribution...

Comment: I know that $\mathbb{E}[X] = \sum_a a\mathbb{P}(X = a)$, but I don't know how to apply that here.

Comment: $$E(X)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty kP(X=k)\qquad P(X=k)=qp^k$$

Comment: @Did Yes, I just wasn't sure why $\mathbb{P}(X=k)=qp^k$... but after you confirmed that this was the correct application and after some thought, the probability that the offspring of some individual is $k$ is indeed just $qp^k$ (it's in the question!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of offspring of a cell is $X$.

The probability that $X=k$ is given by: $~\mathsf P(X=k) = qp^k$ for $k\in\{0, 1, 2,\ldots \}$ and $q=(1-p)$.

The expected value of $X$ is given by : $~\mathsf E(X) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty k~\mathsf P(X=k)$

Thence, using Geometric Series closed form (when $\lvert p\rvert<1)$: $$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X) ~=~& \sum_{k=0}^\infty k~qp^k
\\ ~=~ & (1-p)\sum_{k=0}^\infty kp^k
\\ ~=~ & \dfrac{(1-p)p}{(1-p)^2}
\\ ~=~ & \dfrac{p}{q}
\end{align}$$

That is all.